# What's the difference between this.function() and function() in recursion?

Tags: solidity, contract-debugging, solidity-0.6.x, recursive

I stumbled across some odd behavior that I can't explain regarding recursive functions in Solidity.

As a note, I have attempted to run this on `ganache` in case it is actually `ganache` that is throwing this behavior.

```
contract Foo {
    function bar() public {
        bar(); // This does what I expected, it consumes all available gas and reverts

        this.bar(); // This reverts at a point much below the gas limit
    }
}
```

The `this.bar()` line recurses but in a different way to `bar()`.

The `this` keyword makes the function call an external one i.e. the `msg.sender` becomes the contract and only the top level call is by the `tx.origin` EOA address.

Is there a limit on the number of times an external call can be made and thus causing this revert?

What else could be the cause of this behavior?

Below is an example that causes the behaviour I am describing.

`test.sol`

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.2;

contract test {
    function doNothing() public
    {
        this.doNothing();
    }
}
```

`test.js`

```js
const test = artifacts.require("test")

contract ("test.sol", async accounts => {
    let contract;

    it("do nothing", async () => {
        contract = await test.new();

        await contract.doNothing();
    })
})
```

Running `truffle test -t test.js` over a `ganache` instance results in the following:

```
Contract: test.sol
    1) do nothing
    > No events were emitted


  0 passing (3s)
  1 failing

  1) Contract: test.sol
       do nothing:
     Error: Returned error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert
      at Context.it (test/test.js:9:26)
      at <anonymous>
      at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:160:7)
```

The transaction that reverts consumes `463179` gas whilst the transaction gas limit is `6721975`.

Using `truffle v5.1.42` and `ganache-cli v6.12.1`.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116453/discussion-on-question-by-shiri-whats-the-difference-between-this-function-an).